# Add-Member to add a custom method to a PowerShell object

Tags: powershell, scriptblock

I want to add a custom method to an existing object. My problem is I may not find out how to make it accept parameters.

In this greatly simplified example I want to add a script block to a System.IO.FileInfo-Object to output a specific parameter to the screen:

```
$NewMethodScript = {
 param(
        [String] $Param1
    )
write-host $this.$Param1
#Do lots of more stuff, call functions, etc...
}

$FInfo = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new("C:\File.txt")
$FInfo | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name NewMethod -Value $NewMethodScript

$FInfo.NewMethod "DirectoryName"
```

Comment: `$FInfo.NewMethod("DirectoryName")`